# Simple way to define UITableView Cell template in iOS similar to how it's done with MvxListView in Android

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, data-binding, mvvmcross

Currently there is very easy way to define `MvxItemTemplate` and handle it in Android:

```
    <MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/grdEvents"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/eventslistcell"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Events; ItemClick GoEventDetails" />
```

And that's it. No additional adapters, no complications. Only separate `axml` file for the cell.

Is there a similar way to do that with iOS project? (MvvmCross documentation is still very very poor about that).

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You can define your own custom class derived from `MvxTableViewCell`, which provides the layout used for an individual cell. For a complete sample see the [WorkingWithCollections sample](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/WorkingWithCollections/Collections.iOS) on GitHub.

In short, you first define your custom cell as `MvxTableViewCell`. You can do so [with a `xib` file](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/WorkingWithCollections/Collections.iOS/Views/Samples/Cells) as well as [without it](http://benjaminhysell.com/archive/2014/04/mvvmcross-custom-mvxtableviewcell-without-a-nib-file/).

Then you need to create an instance of `MvxSimpleTableViewSource` or `MvxStandardTableViewSource` and pass into it the name of your custom cell `nib` or the type of your custom cell class:

```
var tableViewSource = 
    new MvxSimpleTableViewSource( tableView, typeof( MyCustomCell ), "MyCustomCell" );
```

The third parameterd specifies an cell type identifier, which would come handy if you used multiple different types of cells in one table view. The system then uses it to recycle the correct type of cell that it needs.

Finally you set the instance as the `Source` of your table view:

```
tableView.Source = tableViewSource;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and I believe it helps. However, initially the question was referred to "ready-out-of-the-box" functionality available in MvvmCross for Android layouts, where I didn't need to define any additional classes/wrappers. Does that mean that this is the easiest way to achieve that which you've suggested here?

Comment: Well, in the Android solution you don't have to define a class, but still have to create a layout file with the cell layout. In iOS this is more complicated, because in contrast to Android MvvmCross bindings cannot be "integrated" into xib, so the custom backing class is really necessary to make it all work... There are a few built-in system cells in iOS, but those are very simple and for most scenarios you will probably need more than that.

Comment: could you actually also tell how I can specify the binding of the data and my elements withing the custom cell?

Comment: I know there is the way to achieve that with defining of binding within the Cell code (constructor, for instance), like `DelayBind` etc. But it's complicated and not so flexible. However, is it possible to reuse "Standard" cells binding schema like this:             `var source = new MvxStandardTableViewSource(tblData, UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, new NSString("MyCell"), "MyCellProperty Title2", UITableViewCellAccessory.None);`? I tried to define this field as public property of MyCell class, but it doesn't work still. That way would have much sense. MvvmCross reflection issue?

Comment: @Agat If this has resolved your issue, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is resolved.

Comment: Martin, as I mentioned in my previous answer, this is still kind of complicated approach and not quite what I was looking initially.